# NSDateFormatter format for "Sat, 15 Aug 2015 08:42:05 GMT"

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am starting to get mad. ;-) All I want to do is to convert this relatively simple date string "Sat, 15 Aug 2015 08:42:05 GMT" into a NSDate.

```
let dateString = "Sat, 15 Aug 2015 08:42:05 GMT"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM YYYY HH:mm:ss zzz"
let date = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)
```

But I get:

```
po date 
2014-12-27 09:42:05 UTC
```

What am I missing?

In compliance to the [AppleDoc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) I am using [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) to look for my patterns.

Comment: I'm getting `nil` instead (XCode7)

Comment: I still use XCode6. But that might be a hint?!

Comment: I removed "Sat, " and "EEE, " and got correct results (I18N). Maybe that would be a way?

Comment: Tried that in a playground just now. (I should think of those more often.) Sadly doesn't help in XCode6. Though I am Dec. 21 now. Removing the timezone doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ooops. I just see that this now returns "22.12.2014 09:42" :-?

Comment: I think you want the year to be `yyyy` (lowercase)...